# How to link input button display:none behavior with the label

Tags: javascript, html

I want to link an input `display: none` button to a label so that when I click on the label, it has the same behavior of my hidden input button. How can I do this?

Below is my HTML5 code:

```
<label for="model1" class="uploadFile">File...</label>
<input id="model1" type="file" name="model1" class="model1" style="display:none;" th:required="true"  />
```

Comment: Your goal is not clear at all here. Are you saying that you want the `input` to become visible when the `label` is clicked?

Comment: Your question is quite impossible to understand. could you please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: please make this question clearer

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `label` to trigger a `click event` on the `input type=file`, then use:

```
$('.uploadFile').click(function() {
  $("#model1").unbind('click').bind('click');
})
```

I've also added how to add the file name to the label:

```
$('#model1').change(function() {
 var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
 $('.uploadFile').text(filename)
})
```

```js
$('.uploadFile').click(function() {
  $("#model1").unbind('click').bind('click');
})

$('#model1').change(function() {
 var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
 $('.uploadFile').text(filename)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="model1" class="uploadFile">File...</label>
   <input id="model1"  type="file"    name="model1" class="model1"
style="display:none;" th:required="true"  />
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use javascript, and have something like:

```
<label for="model1" class="uploadFile" onclick="handleClick()">File...</label>
```

and then define a `handleclick()` function which will process what you need to do with the button press.

The `handleclick()` could be as simple as:

```
$('#element').click();
```

or

```
$('#element').trigger('click');
```

Comment: I think the more important part to show is the bit you left out

Comment: I changed the default label of a file type input button with a label. I hide the input buton with the display: none property. I would like when I click on the new label, that I have the same behavior of my input button. The html code is above